# python 3.x loop through an array find the repeating elements and sum them into a new element

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

hi i've been trying to find a way to find the sum of the repeating elements within an array.

I have this array of data and I would like to find a way to go through it and find the sum of the elements that are repeated.

```
data_set = [{'service_general_id': 46, 'service_general_qty': 1000.0}, {'service_general_id': 46, 'service_general_qty': 56000.0}, {'service_general_id': 44, 'service_general_qty': 56000.0}]
```

the result that I have in mind is something like this:

```
data_result = [{'service_general_id': 46, 'service_general_qty': 57000.0}, {'service_general_id': 44, 'service_general_qty': 56000.0}]
```

I've been trying to go through this way to find the repeats.

```py
for servicio in provisiones_originales_dict:
    k, v = servicio['servicio_general_id'], servicio['servicio_general_qty']
```

but I have not found the logic to find the repeated ones and add them in a result array

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe you should write some code?

Comment: Ok there's no question here, I just see a demand. There's zero effort from you being demonstrated. That's why you're getting so many downvotes so fast. To get an idea of what is allowed and expected on this site, you need to read the [tour], the [ask] page, this [help/on-topic] topic, and the page [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251)

Comment: I apologize for sounding bad now I see that I have phrased the question in a rude way. I've been trying to go through the original array but I can't find a way to determine if the element is present inside another, I've seen many examples of only elements but I can't find the logic to do it with an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create `dict` base on `service_general_id` as `key` then compute `sum` then convert to result dict like below:

```
>>> data_set = [{'service_general_id': 46, 'service_general_qty': 1000.0}, {'service_general_id': 46, 'service_general_qty': 56000.0}, {'service_general_id': 44, 'service_general_qty': 56000.0}]

>>> dct = {}
>>> for (key ,value) in (dct.values() for dct in data_set):
...    dct[key] = value + dct.get(key,0)
>>> dct
{46: 57000.0, 44: 56000.0}
    
>>> res = [{'service_general_id':key , 'service_general_qty':value} for key, value in dct.items()]
>>> res
[{'service_general_id': 46, 'service_general_qty': 57000.0},
 {'service_general_id': 44, 'service_general_qty': 56000.0}]
```